# Spring Boot : restarter not initialized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When the  spring boot version is **1.5.3.RELEASE**, I got the following error while starting the application

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Restarter has not been initialized
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.getInstance(Restarter.java:563) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationPreparedEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:75) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:48) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:367) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.*.SpringBootWebApplication.main(SpringBootWebApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
```

**NB**: when the version is changed to **1.4.2.RELEASE**, it works fine and didn't throw the above exception

Comment: For starters stop mixing versions. When you use 1.5.3 you still have 1.4.2 jars on your class path. So your dependencies are wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your comments. I removed the 1.4.2.RELEASE jars from the classpath and now its working

Answer (score 10):

Problem exist due to version of artifact. Remove the version in **org.springframework.boot spring-boot-devtools** in pom.xml.

#### Maven

Inside pom.xml

```html
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  <dependencies>
```

#### Gradle

Inside build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this error due to lombok. May be becuase of having multiple versions of lombok being used in different projects. Deleting lombok folder from .m2 resolved this problem.